# How to correctly read height of iframe's contents after changing the contents in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am programming a website creator where user is allowed to visually create some website structure in an iframe.
The iframe's height must get updated always when the iframe's content is updated. I'm having some difficulties in understanding why height of iframe's content is sometimes read incorrectly in JavaScript after dynamically changing the content. I made a test script which shows the thing:
http://vickcreator.com/test/test.php
with iframe here: http://vickcreator.com/test/test2.php
As you can see by looking in source code in browser (or below) the first button fills the iframe with many boxes and immidiately tries to update iframe's height which does not work - it looks like the height is not updated yet in DOM (or something like that), so I though the second button will do - it uses 1 second of delay (doesn't really matter how many seconds, I tried even 5 sec), but no, here height is read wrong (a little less than should be) which results in vertical scroll bar (tested on Firefox and Chrome) - WHY ? Then pressing "set height" fixes the issue. The same happens (first "clear" to reset) when pressing "ONLY fill", then"set height" - then pressing "set height" second time fixes this.

Two questions:

- is there any event saying that updating of iframe's content has completed ?
- how to correctly read the outerHeight ? I tried:

---

```
$( '#iframe' ).contents().find( 'html' ).outerHeight();

$( '#iframe' ).contents().find( 'body' ).outerHeight();

$( '#iframe' ).contents().find( '#wrapper' ).outerHeight();

$( '#iframe' ).contents().outerHeight();
```

---

None of these worked. 
Below is source code of both files. I didn't use code snippet in StackOverflow because it does not allow me to use iframes.
I can update the code on my server if you need. Thanks for help.

test.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://searchcode.com/codesearch/raw/73742722/"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setHeight()
    {
        var newHeight = $( '#iframe' ).contents().find( 'html' ).outerHeight();
        $( '#iframe' ).height( newHeight );
        $( '#heightText' ).html( newHeight );
    }

    function fill()
    {
        for( i=0; i<1000; ++i )
        {
            $( '#iframe' ).contents().find( '#wrapper' ).append( '<div class="box"></div>' );
        }
    }

    function go( delay )
    {
        fill();

        if( ! delay )
        {
            setHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            $( document ).everyTime( 1000, function(i) 
            {
                setHeight();
            }, 1 );
        }
    }

    function clearContent()
    {
        $( '#iframe' ).contents().find( '#wrapper' ).empty();
        $( '#iframe' ).height( '500px' );
        $( '#heightText' ).html( 500 );
    }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .box { border:1px dashed black; height:50px; width:50px; margin:5px; display:inline-block; }
        .coloured { background: darkgreen; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="go( false );">Fill and set height with NO delay</button>
    <button onclick="go( true );">Fill and set height WITH delay (1s)</button>
    <button onclick="setHeight();">Set height</button>
    <button onclick="fill();">ONLY fill</button>
    <button onclick="clearContent();">Clear</button>
    Height:<span id="heightText"></span>
    <iframe id="iframe" style="width:100%; height:500px;" src="test2.php"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

test2.php (iframe):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .box { border:1px dashed black; height:50px; width:50px; margin:5px; display:inline-block; }
        .coloured { background: darkgreen; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In Google Chrome in console (F12) I typed monitorEvents(document.body.querySelector('#iframe')); to check if changing the iframe's contents will trigger any events, but it does not.

Comment: I added another button "Fill and set height 3 times" (see source code in browser for the source of function goTripple(); ) which is weird solution and it works unfortunately only in Firefox. It doesn't work in Chrome. In Chrome the "set height" button behaves strange - it returns different height values. So the questions is still open. Anybody ?

Comment: Hello? Anyone knows solution?